# GET em vez de DELETE no webservice REST

Tags: java, web-service

Estou tentando fazer um delete no meu banco utilizando um `webservice rest(JAVA)`, ele carrega tudo certinho, mas hora que mando o teste ele da `Method not allowed`.

Obs: Estou utilizando `Netbeans`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que eu percebi o WS esta tentando realizar um `GET` e não um DELETE: `GET SolicitaçãoFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (405)`

então olhei minha classe e não faço ideia do que esta errado:

WS:

```
@DELETE
    @Path("Banco/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteBanco(@PathParam("id") int id){

        BancoDAO dao = new BancoDAO();
        String resposta = dao.deleteBanco(id);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(resposta);
    }
```

DAO:

```
public String deleteBanco(int codigo) {
        try {
            conn = Conexao.obtemConexao();
            String delete = "DELETE FROM BANCO WHERE BCO_COIGO = '?'";

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(delete);
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();

            if (i == 0) {
                return "Erro ao excluir banco";
            } else if (i == 1) {
                return "Banco removido com sucesso...";
            } else if (i > 1) {
                return "Erro 001: \n Problema de SQL, mais de uma informação "
                        + "foi removida, favor entrar em contado com suporte "
            } else {
                return "Erro 301: \n Erro não identificado, "
                        + "favor entrar em contato com suporte.";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Erro ao excluir banco: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Único método GET que possuo:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/get/{nome}")
    public String getBanco(@PathParam("nome") String nome){
        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();
        BancoDAO banco = new BancoDAO();

        if (nome.equals("null")){
            lista = banco.listBanco(0, nome);
        }else{
            lista = banco.listBanco(1, nome);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }
```

Comment: Se aceita uma dica fora da sua pergunta: olhando os endereços rest que criou, sugiro dar uma olhada em alterá-los para ficar mais aderente as boas práticas. Exemplo: mude de `Banco/delete/{id}"` para apenas `bancos/{id}"`

Comment: Se você estiver testando no browser, lembre-se que o mesmo só faz requisições via GET, para fazer um uma requisição via DELETE você pode usar uma ferramenta como o Postman, como já foi sugerido pelo LR10 na resposta dele, e aproveitando o comentário do @Dherik, vale a pena você procurar algum material teórico sobre o assunto, pois realmente o seu mapeamento não ficou muito condizente com a arquitetura Rest, é importante entender a proposta, e assim você saberá como usa-la da melhor forma.

Answer (score 0):

O seu cliente está fazendo um `request` do tipo `GET` muda à requisição para `DELETE` como no exemplo abaixo. Estou usando `POSTMAN`

sua URL eve ficar mais ou menos a sim: `localhost:8080/Banco/delete/1`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]